# got weird results when using the openpyxl module in Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an excel spreadsheet whose data are as follows (from A1 to C3):
[original spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1S9Eu.png)
I want to calculate the chances of none-zero values in a column, then write the result to the last cell in this column. In the case of the third column, the result should be 2/3 = 0.67
Below is the Python script that I wrote to do the same thing, but it gets the wrong result obviously.

The code:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('testXls.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
for colNum in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
    coverCount = 0
    for rowNum in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
        if sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=colNum).value != 0:
            coverCount += 1
    sheet.cell(row=4, column=colNum).value = round(coverCount / 3, 2)
wb.save('testXls2.xlsx')
```

The result:
[result spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b463w.png)

I can't find anything wrong in the code. Could someone enlighten me on this please? I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you write down the value in the fourth line of each iteration, which leads to unnecessary iteration.